# Perlbrew install of 5.30.2 fails

Tags: perl, centos, perlbrew

I'm attempting to install perl 5.30.2 with perlbrew thus: `perlbrew install perl-5.30.2`

however, this install fails

```sh
grep -A2 -B2 -i fail /home/con/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-5.30.2.log
```

shows

```
op/groups.t                                                      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 3 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
```

And the output of that test (from `/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-5.30.2.log`) is

```
# Failed test 1 - perl's `$(' agrees with `id -a 2>/dev/null || id 2>/dev/null' at op/groups.t line 117
op/groups.t ........................................................ 
Failed 1/3 subtests 
    (less 1 skipped subtest: 1 okay)
```

System information (from `/etc/os-release`)

```sh
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.6"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"
```

I have no idea how to debug this.  I'm already running the latest perlbrew version:

```
$ perlbrew --version
/usr/local/bin/perlbrew  - App::perlbrew/0.88
```

and I've already installed patchperl.

I don't see any useful solutions on other links [Why does perlbrew fail while installing perl-5.12.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745586/why-does-perlbrew-fail-while-installing-perl-5-12-2)

How can I debug this to install perl-5.30.2?

Comment: @ikegami I've edited the post to include the output from op/groups.t the lib version doesn't match the executable, well yes, that's what I'm trying to do by installing perlbrew, I don't understand why it would do this

Comment: @ikegami I've edited the post to include the output from `grep -A10 -B10 groups.t fail ~/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-5.30.2.log`

Comment: This problem related to `$(`, which returns the groups to which the process belongs via the `getgid` and `getgroups` system calls. It's probably not going to affect you to install the Perl anyway, which you can do by using `perlbrew install --notest`. But, if you want to take this further, I can try to help. (In fact, I think I helped someone with this very problem before. Ttying to locate that question now.)

Comment: [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57875733/589924) (Unresolved)

Comment: If you want to proceed, provide the output of `id -a` and `./perl -le'print $('` (from `~/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.30.2/perl-5.30.2`)

Comment: If you want to debug yourself, you can run just the failing test file using `./TEST op/groups.t` from the `t` subdirectory. You may need to run `make test_prep` from the main directory (`~/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.30.2/perl-5.30.2`) first.

Comment: @ikegami I'll delete this question, if that's ok with you

Comment: It's up to you, but I don't know why you want to do that.